# how do you take a string of arguments and return the number on dots (.) it contains?

Tags: javascript

for example if i have an email address aril_example@hotmail.co.uk the function will return 2

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
var dots = "aril_example@hotmail.co.uk".split(".").length-1;
```

Using the `split` method you will split the string in substrings, which would be separated one another with a dot. These substrings would be in an array. This is what split returns. Taking the length of the array  and decrementing it by 1 you get that you want.

```js
var dots = "aril_example@hotmail.co.uk".split(".").length-1;
document.write(dots)
```

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of dots, try splitting the string on the dot character, then checking the resulting array length.

```
var str = "aril_example@hotmail.co.uk";
console.log(str.split('.').length-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function howManyDots(input) {
  return (input.match(/\./g) || []).length;
};

howManyDots('aril_example@hotmail.co.uk');

## returns 2
```

[`String.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) takes a regex (in this case, a simple pattern to match all instances of the character `.`) and returns an array of matches. We just want the length of that array.

Comment: `(input.match(/\./g) || []).length`

Comment: ^ True dat. Edited. Thanks @epascarello